# Retrieving Postgres Function JSON type in JPA

Tags: json, postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a postgres function (stored procedure) that returns an out parameter of type json.

Now I have an issue with calling that function in JPA and retreiving the OUT parameter.

```
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_myjson", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
```

The String.class obviously fails. How can I convert this to a valid JSON string. I have access to the postgres function and have the option to change the return type of it. When I changed it to Text, the Text output was not valid JSON.

Any idea how to solve this please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it by changing the return type of the postgres function to character varying

and keeping the return type of the parameter in JPA query to String.class

query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_myjson", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);